# Cocoa writeToFile: with a specific UTI

Tags: cocoa, writetofile, uti

My app exports to CVS but Numbers won't open it because it dosen't have the `public.comma-separated-values-text` UTI. Is there a simple way to apply the UTI to the file as im writing it or do I have to declare it in info.plist? I don't want my app to open CVS files, it just needs to export it's data.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers or Excel opens `CSV` files, not `CVS` files. You see, they are **C** omma **S** eparated **V** alues :)  The system automatically assigns the UTI. So, use the extension `.csv`. CVS is a name of a Drug Store chain.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I messed that up. Thats what I get for making it late at night. Thanks for helping me find the obvious :)

Comment: No problem, in fact I made the same mistakes and wasted a few hours in the past. That's why ;)